# PHP Mysql_fetch_assoc is Omitting last row

Tags: php

In PHP MYSQL_FETCH_ASSOC is omitting Last Row.  This never happened.  But this time it put me into soup at the last moment.

Even I've put up mysql_num_rows the result is 14 records -- but on list it shows only 13 records and the 14th record is omitted.

Any kind of help is Appreciated.

```
                $uno = $_GET["uno"];

                $xtc1 = 'select * from rform where uno="' . $uno . '" order by rno DESC';
                $xtc = mysql_query($xtc1) or die('User Reservation Retrival Error : ' . mysql_error());

                $trno = mysql_fetch_assoc($xtc);
                $trow = mysql_num_rows($xtc);


                echo '<p>List of Onlilne Reservations made by <strong style="font-weight:bold; color:red;">' . ucwords($trno["cname"]) . ' (' . $trow . ')</strong></p>';

                echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">';
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td colspan="5" style=" font-size:14px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; color:red;">' . ucwords($trno["cname"]) . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<th>R.NO</th>';
                            echo '<th>From</th>';
                            echo '<th>To</th>';
                            echo '<th>Date &amp; Time of<Br>Travel</th>';
                            echo '<th>Reserved On</th>';
                        echo '</tr>';   
                    while($mtn = mysql_fetch_assoc($xtc)){
                        $dt = $mtn["csdate"] . ' ' . $mtn["ctime"];
                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>' . $mtn["rno"] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $dt . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $mtn["caddr"] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $mtn["cdest"] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . date('d-M-Y',strtotime($mtn["tstamp"])) . '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';   
                    }
                    echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `$trno = mysql_fetch_assoc($xtc)` that you sem to be discarding. This is your missing row. Just remove that line.

Comment: That Was It, Thank You Kolink

Answer (score 0):

deleting the first `$trno = mysql_fetch_assoc($xtc);` will solve this problem.

In case you need to read the first line of `$xtc` before the loop. You can change while loop to do-while, without deleted the first `$mtn = mysql_fetch_assoc($xtc);`

```
do{
    //whatever
}while($mtn = mysql_fetch_assoc($xtc));
```